# Scala 3 SBT project - not found type

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala-3

I'm learning Scala and functional programming however I encountered an issue and really have no idea how to solve it so far.

I have a class:

```
package io.github.vcvitaly.grokkingfp
package ch6


class TvShowAttributesParser {
  ...some code...
}
```

I also have another class that depends on the first one (I come from Java and decided to break everything into small classes for easier testing), it's in the same package, however Intellij says that type is not available:

```
package io.github.vcvitaly.grokkingfp
package ch6


class TvShowParser(attributesParser: TvShowAttributesParser) {
  ...nothing here yet...
}
```

`TvShowAttributesParser` is underlined with red here and I have no idea why. Also, my classes are not available to my test classes with the same error.

[image]

What could be possibly wrong? Scala 3, Sbt 1.8.3

The link to the repo just in case: https://github.com/vcvitaly/GrokkingFP

Comment: Does compiling outside of IntelliJ give the same result? With `sbt compile`.

Comment: You may try to 1. close Idea. 2. delete .idea directory 3. reopen project. If it not help, you may try to downgrade java version ([java-scala compatibility](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/jdk-compatibility/overview.html)) (or upgrade sbt version, see the same site). And yep, Gael gave a good advice too

Comment: @GaëlJ running `sbt compile` in console also solved in in Idea too, which is strange ... Anyway, thanks. If you want - add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.